# Asp.Net Application Structure

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an ASP.NET web form application, and this is the structure:

[image]

As shown, there are two sub applications: `security` and `webservice`.

Now I have two problems:

**1 - Shared Library**

Both the `security` and `webservice` will use some shared libraries like `log4net` and etc, I want to put them in the `t/bin`, but it seems that the sub application can not access the dlls in it's parent/bin.

**2 - Development**

During the development, once I open the whole `t` application in Visual Studio, it seems that the `*.cs` in `webservice` module can not access the code inside `t/webservice/App_Code`.

Are there any best practices?

The reason I made the `security` and `webservice` as sub-applications is that these two modules can work on their own, and can be integrated to other applications out of the box (and they are developed by someone else)

Comment: See my update, I add the reason why I use the extra application.

Comment: Why do you want them to share the same dlls?  Dlls take up so little space, just give each one a copy of what they need in their bin

Comment: Can you just put those sub-apps as separate applications in your solution?